# System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost implements IDisposable but Dispose is not public

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

Why is that?

This is not a question about the using keyword.

Comment: Maybe this other question resolves your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253266/why-explicit-implementation-of-a-interface-can-not-be-public

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) implements the IDisposable interface [explicitly](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228051305/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx). This prevents that interface complicating the the ServiceHost class itself. It also avoids situations where more than one interface implemented by a class defines a method with the same signature.

The Dispose method can be accessed by casting the ServiceHost object to an IDisposable.

Also [helpful Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143423/9293869)  around it.