# Bind to explicit interface indexer implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I bind to to an explicit interface indexer implementation?

Suppose we have two interfaces

```
public interface ITestCaseInterface1
{
    string this[string index] { get; }
}

public interface ITestCaseInterface2
{
    string this[string index] { get; }
}
```

a class implementing both

```
public class TestCaseClass : ITestCaseInterface1, ITestCaseInterface2
{
    string ITestCaseInterface1.this[string index] => $"{index}-Interface1";

    string ITestCaseInterface2.this[string index] => $"{index}-Interface2";
}
```

and a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestCaseClass}">
                <TextBlock Text="**BINDING**"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I tried so far without any success

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:ITestCaseInterface1[abc])}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:ITestCaseInterface1)[abc]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:ITestCaseInterface1.Item[abc])}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:ITestCaseInterface1.Item)[abc]}" />
```

How should my `Binding` look like?

Thanks

Comment: Which .Net Version are you using?

Comment: @LittleBit 4.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not in XAML access the indexer, which is explicit implementation of interface.

What you can is to write for each interface a value converter, use appropriate converter in binding and set `ConverterParameter` to the desired Key:

```
public class Interface1Indexer : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as ITestCaseInterface1)[parameter as string];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("one way converter");
    }
}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource interface1Indexer}, ConverterParameter='abc'" />
```

And of course bound properties have to be `public`, whereas explicit implementation has special state. This question can be helpful: [Why Explicit Implementation of a Interface can not be public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253266/why-explicit-implementation-of-a-interface-can-not-be-public)

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer and time. I was hoping that I missed something, cause with properties everything works fine. Strange thing that Indexer won't work.

Comment: @nosale The normal `public` indexer will work, the explicit implementation of interface for indexer will not work.